# JavaScript execution blocks and the message queue

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout, nonblocking

Is it possible that a timeout function with a delay of 0ms `setTimeout(function, 0)` could be called after a loop execution block or would the encompassing function block **always** be completed first?

```
setTimeout(function(){ //something in here }, 0);

function myFunction() {
  // do something
  // loop block

  // could timeout = 0 be scheduled to execute here?

  // do more things
}

myFunction()
```

In my context (Angular 2), it would be interesting to know whether Angular's `ApplicationRef.tick()`, to check for data-binding/component changes, could potentially be called before I am finished manipulating the two-way binding property within nested loops?

Is a function call and all subsequent sub function calls equivalent to a single item in the message queue or is it broken down to each execution block being individual items in the message queue? Therefore `setTimeout(..., 0)` potentially entering between execution blocks in the queue?

Comment: If you want to learn more about the JS call stack and why asynchronous code is always called once the synchronous code has finished running, I encourage you to [watch this great talk](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can treat javaScript as "one thread" - there is only one peace of code running in any point of time. Any timeout will execute after current flow finishes.
Moreover, while executing javascript page becomes non-responsive -- you cant do any action.

Some demonstration:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log(1) }); 
var d = new Date();
var i = 0; for(; i < 1e9; i++) {}
console.log(i);
console.log('Passed ' + (new Date() - d));

>> 1000000000
>> Passed ~2000
>> 1
```

Comment: thanks, knew it was "single thread" but wasn't sure if JS engines broke up execution blocks and queued them in which case a timeout could be inserted at the nearest point. But I understand how that's not the case. Thanks again.